# How to use java jar files in saleforce?

Tags: apex, visualforce

Hi I got one jar file from Java which do encrypt and decry pt the values 
now i need to use jar file in apex or VF.
is there any way to do that? or do you have any other solution to encrypt and decry pt order numbers in between salesforce and Java  side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Salesforce docs It is NOT possible.
[Access Jar file in Apex](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000004195&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.in%2F&type=1)
A Webservice is needed here. Or you can host these file on Heroku then make a request from Salesforce.

For Encryption and decryption you can use Salesforce [Crypto Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Crypto_Class) and can pass the data.